# Dynamically add input value(typed by user) to another field (which has default value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple problem, yet I couldn't figure out the solution.

What I want to do is to get one input field's value and add it into another field's value (be aware another field has already a value so what i'm trying to do is add strings simply)

**Here's what I tried :**

1) [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/45LfG/)

```
$('#mobile_username').val($(this).val());
```

This one ignores the default value of the 2nd field and just overrides it (Not really what I want)

2) [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4rXRd/)

```
$('#mobile_username').val += ($(this).val());
```

So I tried the add first field's value to second one's but nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the `defaultValue` of the element and concatenate the strings:

```
$('#flat_name').keyup(function () {
    var v = this.value;
    $('#mobile_username').val(function() {
       return this.defaultValue + v;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4hTE/

Comment: Never knew about `defaultValue`, very nice!

Comment: First time seeing `defaultValue` +1

Answer (score 1):

This is just another solution for those who want to use other way beside `defaultValue`:

```
var flat = $('#mobile_username').val();

$('#flat_name').keyup(function () {
    var generated = this.value;

    $('#mobile_username').val(flat + generated);
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x4hTE/3/)

Comment: A good alternative. In fact, I think I'll replace my code with your approach